# Figma: how to make auto layout frame contain a stroke's width

Tags: stroke, tools, layout, figma

I'm trying to use an auto layout frame to contain a hamburger menu. The lines of the hamburger menu should be entirely contained within the auto layout frame.

I applied the following settings to the containing frame called "hamburger", which I thought would do what I want:

1. Spacing mode: space between
2. Strokes: included

[image: hamburger frame]

but as you can see in the screenshot, the top line sits on top of the auto layout frame rather than inside it.
Here are the settings on the individual lines:

[image: Individual line on hamburger]

How can I get the top line to sit within the auto layout frame instead of on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use filled rectangles instead of lines with strokes.

[image]

Comment: Possible, but seems as though I should be able to achieve it with strokes as well.

Comment: @MikeEng - well you could perhaps draw an invisible rectangle (no fill, no stroke) over the top of the hamburger.